# Rails using custom helper in config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom helper:

```
module PostsHelper
    def post_path(post)
        year = post.published_at.year

        month = post.published_at.month
        month = "0#{ month }" if month < 10

        day = post.published_at.day
        day = "0#{ day }" if day < 10

        "#{ blog_path }/#{ year }/#{ month }/#{ day }/#{ post.raw_title }"
    end
end
```

I would like to use the helper in my config/sitemap.rb file which I am using to build a sitemap.

I am trying this in the file:

```
Post.posts.each do |bp|
    add PostsHelper::post_path(bp), priority: 1, changefreq: 'weekly'
end
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `post_path' for PostsHelper:Module
```

Trying to include the module doesn't help either (`include PostsHelper`):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<SitemapGenerator::Interpreter:0x000000025086b8>
```

How can I use a custom Rails helper in a config file?

Comment: You are calling `post_path` at class level while it is defined at instance level; try with `def self.post_path(post)`

Comment: @mdesantis ok I agree there, but how do I call it at the instance level? That is what I really want to do

Comment: Maybe you should learn more about [Ruby modules](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html)

Comment: The problem is if I call ```include PostsHelper``` I get this: ```NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<SitemapGenerator::Interpreter:0x000000025086b8>```

Comment: Oh you are referring to the config file, I'm sorry, I didn't get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the helper module  in your `config/sitemap.rb`

Add this to the top of the `config/sitemap.rb` file

```
SitemapGenerator::Interpreter.send :include, PostsHelper
```